# Phagemid display

Tags: protein-binding, protein-engineering, protein-evolution

If I'm using a bacteriophage for phage display and I'm trying to avoid avidity effects by using a helper phage what would be the best way to maintain a large library size while keeping everything monomeric? I'm asking in terms of maintaining an appropriate infection ratio and or phage tricks and tools to maintain the that stoichiometry.

Comment: If you don't end up getting an answer here, I would recommend reposting on researchgate

Answer (score 10):

I found article in Nature:

[A helper phage to improve single-chain antibody presentation in phage display](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v19/n1/full/nbt0101_75.html)

> **Experimental protocol**
>
> Standard cloning procedures, determination of colony-forming units and
> plaque-forming units, and immunoblot after PAGE were carried out
> according to Sambrook et al.
>
> **Construction of the packaging cell line.**
>
> DH5alpha/pIII
> [M13KO7DeltapIII]. The M13 pIII gene fused to promoter P/A1/04/03
> (ref. 17) was inserted into the multiple cloning site of the
> lambdaattP plasmid pLDR9 (ref. 18). The origin of replication and the
> kanamycin resistance gene were cut out and the remaining
> lambdaattP-pIII nonreplicative DNA was religated. Escherichia coli
> DH5alpha containing plasmid pLDR8 (ref. 18) were transformed with the
> lambdaattP-pIII nonreplicative DNA and plated on agar plates
> containing 25 mug/ml ampicillin. After incubation overnight at 42°C,
> the colonies obtained were replica-plated and ampicillin-resistant
> clones were identified, named E. coli DH5alpha/pIII. They were
> subsequently transformed with M13KO7DeltapIII, resulting in the
> packaging cell line E. coli DH5alpha/pIII [M13KO7DeltapIII].
>
> **Production of phage.**
>
> To obtain M13KO7DeltapIII helper phage,
> M13KO7DeltapIII DNA was electrotransfected into E. coli K802
> containing pNDI (ref. 15). To obtain hyperphage, M13KO7DeltapIII DNA
> was electrotransfected into E. coli DH5alpha/pIII. Phage were produced
> by cultivation in the presence of 0.5 mM
> isopropyl-beta-D-thiogalactoside (IPTG) at 30°C for 24 h with shaking
> at 200 r.p.m. Escherichia coli Top10F' or E. coli Xl1blue carrying the
> pSEXphOx(Yol) phagemid or a scFv library in pSEX81, respectively, were
> infected with a helper phage preparation at a OD600 of 0.1 at a
> multiplicity of infection of 20 as described.
>
> **Phage quantification by ELISA.**
>
> Dilution series of phage were coated in
> 100 mM NaHCO3, pH 8.6 in MaxiSorb ELISA plates (Life Technologies,
> Karsruhe, Germany) for 16 h at 4°C. Blocking was done with 2% skim
> milk powder in PBS (137 mM NaCl, 3 mM KCl, 8 mM Na2HPO4, 1 mM KH2PO4,
> pH 7.3) for 2 h at room temperature. Phage were detected with the
> monoclonal mouse antibody B62-FE2 (Progen, Heidelberg, Germany)
> specifically binding an epitope on the pVIII major coat protein of the
> M13 phage. M13KO7 phage of known colony-forming units were used for
> standardization.
>
> **Immunoblot.**
>
> Approximately 1010 phage were applied per lane on a 10%
> polyacrylamide gel. Blocking was done with 2% skim milk powder in PBS
> for 2 h at room temperature. Immunostaining was done with the mouse
> mAb anti-g3p (MoBiTec, Göttingen, Germany) recognizing the pIII coat
> protein of M13KO7, visualized with 3,3', 5,5'-tetramethylbenzidene
> (TMB) substrate (Promega, Madison, WI).
>
> **Antigen-binding phage ELISA.**
>
> Dilution series of BSA-phOx antigen in
> 100 mM NaHCO3, pH 8.6, were coated in MaxiSorb ELISA plates (Life
> Technologies) for 16 h at 4°C. After blocking of unspecific binding
> with 2% skim milk powder in PBS for 2 h at room temperature, 2 times
> 109 single-chain phage diluted in 2% skim milk powder in PBS were
> applied to each well for 1 h at room temperature. After washing six
> times with 400 mul PBS per well, the bound phage were detected with
> mAb B62-FE2 as described above.
>
> **Panning.**
>
> A human scFv fragment library in pSEX81 with a calculated
> maximal complexity of 2 times 107 was generated from peripheral
> lymphocyte preparations as described21. Tetanus toxin obtained from
> Virotech (Rüsselsheim, Germany) was coated to six ELISA wells (Life
> Technologies) at a concentration of 0.1 mug/ml in 100 mM NaHCO3, pH
> 8.6, for 16 h at 4°C. The wells were blocked with 2% skim milk in PBS for 2 h at room temperature, after which 1011 phage of the library
> were applied to each well and incubated at 4°C overnight. After five
> washes with PBS/0.1% Tween and five with PBS, bound phage were eluted
> with 1 mug/ml trypsin (Life Technologies) in PBS for 15 min at room
> temperature. Eluted phage were used for the infection of 20 ml of E.
> coli XL1blue at a OD600 of 0.4. Infected bacteria were grown on
> Luria–Bertani agar plates containing glucose and ampicillin, scratched
> from the plates, and used for the production of antibody phage for the
> next round of panning as previously described.

[image]

Comment: Looks great Devashish Das. I'll wait until I'm sure of not getting a better answer, but I think that paper pretty much covered it.

Comment: I appreciate that.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for answering such an old question. I'm not entirely sure if this solves the avidity issues though.

Comment: @bobthejoe: Thanks!! Can you add a little bit what I am missing in this?